# & ampersand in SparQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

Okay guys, have a trouble. I have simple sqparql query with filter.

```
  FILTER (?objectRdfType IN ( sym:Some&Some ))
```

I receive Malformed error becouse  in Sparql & - is a symbol to create some variable. But I need this ampersand is name. How can i  fix that?

Comment: specs for prefixed names are online: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#prefNames - use the full URI or escape it via  \ , i.e. `FILTER (?objectRdfType IN ( sym:Some\&Some ))`

Comment: To tell the truth i didnt undersatnd how to fix my problem. I read a lot of time this manual. Can you describe a little bit deeper? And  in my project this query is generated by our api. Maybe we can connect out of stack overflow. Ms Teams or Skype

Comment: not sure what you mean, special characters have to be escaped when using in prefixed URIs. `sym:Some&Some` is a prefixed URI, the `&` has to be escaped with a backslash char \ in front of it. Write `sym:Some\&Some` instead of `sym:Some&Some`. If it's your API you should make it escape special characters according to the SPARQL standard or just use the full URI instead of a prefixed URI